# TsLint/TsConfig: Module 'shared' is not listed as dependency in package.json

Tags: typescript, tslint, tsconfig

I'm trying to create the following monorepo structure:

```
node_modules
project-1
  | tsconfig.json
  | src
project-2
  | tsconfig.json
  | src
shared
  | src
```

I'd like both projects 1 and 2 to be able to import from shared. In both tsconfigs I added to paths `'shared': '[../shared]'` and this allows me to directly import code from shared. However, Tslint complains with `Module 'shared' is not listed as dependency in package.json`. Any ideas on how I can make the linter recognise the `shared` folder in both projects, without disabling the tslint rule?

Answer (score 1):

Inside `tslint.json` you can specify a whitelist of folders alongside the rule:

```
"no-implicit-dependencies": [true, ["app", "environments", "shared"]],
```